# Why in Python Selenium click() not working but send_keys('\n') is working?

Tags: python, selenium, click, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

I have a web page with more few buttons with same class and name and when clicked they just disappear and do nothing. So I first tried this but it didn't work:

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn"]')
buttons[1].click()
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn"]')
buttons[2].click()
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn"]')
buttons[3].click()
```

And then found a solution with:

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn"]')
buttons[1].send_keys('\n')
```

I am new to Python so can anyone explain me what is the reason for not working with click but with send_keys('\n')?

Comment: Try using `send_keys` on the actual input itself, not the button.

Comment: Check that your element is the actual button

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the WebElement type, some elements do not accept clicks even if the website intends for you to click them -- instead of sending keys, you could try using a Javascript `click()` function to see if that works. It's a bit more consistent than sending keys, because you are still performing a click:

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn"]')

# click button using javascript
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", buttons[1])
```

The reason we need to use Javascript usually has to do with a limitation on the web page itself.